SVG 'auto-start-reverse' attribute prevents a document from opening in Visio and leads to unexpected behaviour
I have a simple SVG file that defines an arrowhead at attaches in to the end of the line like this:
  <defs>
    <!-- A marker to be used as an arrowhead -->
    <marker
      id="arrow"
      viewBox="0 0 10 10"
      refX="5"
      refY="5"
      markerWidth="6"
      markerHeight="6"
      orient="auto-start-reverse">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <!-- A line with a marker -->
  <line
    x1="10"
    y1="10"
    x2="90"
    y2="90"
    stroke="black"
    marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>

When I try to open this SVG in Visio I get an error and can't open it. After some observations and a few tries I found out that Visio has a problem with this attribute: orient="auto-start-reverse".
So when I changed it to orient="auto" I could open a file in Visio with no problems, however I noticed that the arrowhead was detached from the line and basically 'floated' far away from it, beyond the limits of the canvas (while in a browser it was still displayed correctly).
Therefore, I'm curious if anyone has ever observed a similar behaviour and perhaps knows what causes it or how to fix it?
(It's important for me not no 'paint' a new arrowhead in Visio and delete the previous one, but to actually fix this).
Thanks!

Change the software you're using to create the SVG not to use that value. I'm not sure what the problem is here.
